# Symfony 3- select query

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony and I'm having a hard time developing a query ... thanks if anyone could help me

What I need is
select id and code from table where id = userid and code = usercode

if the values ​​are equal if statement to insert data into the database, otherwise error message

i try this

```html
 $teste = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Codigo');
        $query = $teste->createQueryBuilder('p')
          ->where('p.codigo = :codigo')
          ->andWhere('p.utilizadorID = :user')
          ->setParameter('codigo', $codigo)
          ->setParameter('user', $user)
          ->getQuery();
        }
    $cod = $query->getResult();

  if ( $cod <> NULL) {
  $link = $data['linkpodcast'];
  
  $podcast->setUrl($link);  
  $podcast->setIdUser($user);
  $sn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();      
  $sn -> persist($podcast);
    
  $sn -> flush();
            
  $this->addFlash(
    'notice',
    'Podcast Adicionado'
  );
  return $this->redirectToRoute('gravar_list');
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Don't be in a hurry, begin by the query, you will do additional treatment as a second step.

Comment: @goto i edit the question

Comment: Why do you think your query doesn't work? seems fine to me

Comment: @goto i get error on $cod... i edit again